# Анализ текста в соответствии с шаблоном

Tags: python, nltk

Задача - определять соответствие текста заданной структуре\требованиям. 
Структура документов (студенческие работы) бывает разной для своего типа. 
Обобщенная структура выглядит следующим образом: `Титульный лист, Оглавление\Содержание, Введение, Основная часть, Заключение, Список литературы, Приложения`.

Так вот мне нужно понимать :

1. Присутствует ли структурная единица в документе (тит.лист, основная часть и и т.д)
2. Иметь возможность выделять ее из текста , для подсчета ее объема и др. параметров.
3. Плюс доп операции например подсчет кол-ва источников в списке литературы.

Скрипт грубо говоря должен решать вопрос валидации документа .

Возможно стоит использовать nltk. Но вопрос как кластеризировать параграфы?
И если получится кластеризировать параграфы , можно ли будет находить индекс (темы\лабла (Буквально - Введение и т.д)) ?

Или же я все сильно усложняю и есть более простой подход для реализации такой идеи ? 
Какой подход или алгоритм вы бы посоветовали ?

Comment: Думаю, многое упирается в формат документа. Если это MS Doc, то можно относительно легко выделять заголовки разного уровня, легко по ним построить структуру документа (если заголовки корректно используются).

Comment: Как человек может понять есть введение, заключение, приложения глядя на документ? Какие формальные признаки?

Comment: Кластеризация не бывает сама по себе. Кластеризуется объект всегда - говоря формальным языком - в пространстве параметров. Выделение параметров - опять-же всегда - задача исследователя.  Вопрос - по каким параметрам вы собираетесь кластеризовать параграфы? .

Comment: Да , формат документа MS Word .Для документа есть ГОСТ. Заголовки выделяются особым образом : прописные буквы и по середине листа. Я думал сделать так построчно проходится по документу , встречаем такой заголовок значит относим строку к определенному "кластеру". Но к примеру титульный лист и содержание не будут иметь такой "метки" , но по идее их можно обработать как исключения.Хотя такой подход как мнне кажется не идеален